# Is it possible to have multiple CoverFlow in same Android activity? How can we manage multiple CoverFlow listeners in same activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, fragment, coverflow

I have implemented the basic cover flow using http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html and it is working fine. Now I am trying to use multiple CoverFlow in same activity but can't do it. I am not able to understand how can I set multiple listeners in the same activity.

I am using a listview to show multiple CoverFlow in the same activity. I have written a custom adapter to inflate the listview with CoverFlow but that is resulting in same CoverFlow and same listeners on all the CoverFlow.

Comment: Please post your code